# How to call super class delegate method from subclass delegate method in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nsoutlineview

There is example class:

```
@interface OutlineViewController : NSOutlineView <NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation OutlineViewController
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
{
    NSTableCellView *result = nil;
if (myCondition)
{
// ...
    return result;
} else {
// how return defult?
}
}

@end
```

Is there possibility call default realization from delegate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `super` keyword to refer to the parent class as you've done in your comment:

```
if (myCondition) {
    //...your implementation here
}
else {
    return [super outlineView:outlineview heightOfRowByItem:item];
}
```

For extra points, you might use `-respondsToSelector:` to  check that `super` responds to the method in question.

**Update:** I just noticed that the superclass in this case is `NSOutlineView` itself. This is quite confusing -- views and view controllers are different things, so calling something descended from a view a "view controller" is not a good plan. Also, note that the docs advise that ["Subclassing NSOutlineView is not recommended."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsoutlineview_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000110-SW17)

Nevertheless, I think I understand your question better now -- I think that by "default realization" you mean not the inherited version of the delegate method, but the behavior that the outline view would use if the delegate method weren't implemented at all. In this case, the answer is pretty simple: you can simply do what `NSOutlineView` itself would do. The documentation for `-outlineView:heightOfRowByItem:` says:

> Implement this method to support an outline view with varying row heights.

For fixed row heights, on the other hand, `NSOutlineView` almost certainly uses the `rowHeight` property that it inherits from `NSTableView`. So, you can simply return `rowHeight` in those cases when you don't want to change the row height:

```
if (myCondition) {
    //...your implementation here
}
else {
    return outlineView.rowHeight;
}
```

Comment: Not clear why you get extra points for -respondsToSelector.  If this is an overloaded method, it will work.  If this is not an overloaded method, why would you be calling super in the first place?  Both of these can be determined statically at "code-authorship" time.

Comment: @JeffLaing The methods in the `NSOutlineViewDelegate` protocol are all optional, so one should not assume just from the fact that `super` adopts the delegate protocol that it necessarily implements the method in question. That said, your comment prompted me to look a little more closely at the question -- I didn't notice that the superclass in this case is NSOutlineView itself.

Comment: I get error: OutlineViewController.m:144:12: No visible @interface for 'NSOutlineView' declares the selector 'outlineView:heightOfRowByItem:'

Comment: @DaVinci Right -- I was assuming that by "default realization" you meant that you wanted the inherited version of the method. Please see my update above.

Comment: Ok, return rowHeight works for "- (CGFloat)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView heightOfRowByItem:(id)item". How about "- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item"?

Comment: @DaVinci In general, there's no *straightforward* way to access the delegator's default behavior from a delegate method. In some cases, as above, you can determine what the delegator would do and then do the same thing. In other cases, you'll just need to decide on an acceptable behavior and implement that yourself. For `-...viewForTableColumn:item:` it looks like you can simply return `nil` and not display anything for that column. If that works for you, great; else, decide what view you would want to see and return that.